# How to link old Jenkins settings with newer version?

Tags: jenkins

I upgraded my jenkins server from 1.647 to 1.648 and I cannot see my previous settings in the web browser.

I stopped my jenkins server using `unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`. And replaced previous .war file in Applications folder. Restarted server using load command and lost previous settings. I know my settings are still on the computer. I can still see my previous settings under `Users/Shared/jenkins/Home`

I noticed the jenkins server still shows up when I navigate to `localhost:8080` even after I thought I stopped the server. (I suppose this is part of my problem). Although I'm unsure what's causing it or how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You need to check the Jenkins logs in `/var/log/jenkins` to see what's going wrong at startup.

Comment: I fixed the issue, but still unsure as to why that was happening. I edited my config.xml file to point to the new version and restarted my jenkins server and the computer it was running on.  Thanks for your suggestion Christopher, I'll be sure to check out the logs next time something funky happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, but still unsure as to why that was happening. I edited my config.xml file to point to the new version and restarted my jenkins server and the computer it was running on